# AngularJS: Model Not Updating On ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app which has a text input box that takes a number. This box is bound using `ng-model` to `packsToReplenish`. It also has an `ng-change` that calls `updateAllCalculations()`. The idea being that when I enter a number in the text field, the model updates, and then the `updateAllCalculations` executes. The problem is, as far as I can tell the model never updates, instead staying at 0, regardless of what I enter into the box.

Because of this, my console.log always shows 0 for the output of the bound model, and then the logic fails due to inaccurate data. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Here are the pertinent code snippets:

HTML

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="packsToReplenish" ng-change="updateAllCalculations()" required>
```

JavaScript (in an app and controller of course - just omitted to save space)

```
$scope.packsToReplenish = 0;
$scope.samples = []; //populated elsewhere

$scope.updateAllCalculations = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.samples.length; i++)
        $scope.updateCalculations(i);
}

$scope.updateCalculations = function(idx) {
    console.log("Update Calculations " + idx  + " - " + $scope.packsToReplenish); //always displays 0, and because of this the logic below doesnt execute properly

    if ($scope.samples[idx].packages[0].openBox > 0)
    {
       if ($scope.samples[idx].packages[0].openBox >= $scope.packsToReplenish)
       {
          $scope.samples[idx].packages[0].maxUnitsToUse = $scope.packsToReplenish;
          $scope.samples[idx].packages[0].newOpenBoxUnits = $scope.samples[idx].packages[0].openBox - $scope.packsToReplenish;
       }
       else 
       {
          $scope.samples[idx].packages[0].maxUnitsToUse = $scope.samples[idx].packages[0].openBox;
          $scope.samples[idx].packages[0].newOpenBoxUnits = 0;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/4b5pqr5u/1/. It is working well. Check your `$scope.samples` setting method. Or you may reset `packsToReplenish` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timeout of e.g. 100 milliseconds. Helped with me.

```
$scope.updateAllCalculations = function(idx) {
    $timeout(function() {
        ...
    }, 100)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As we say at my work: 'The first rule of the angular - if something does not work, wrap it in an object'; You have some problem with namespaces;

```
$scope.tmpData = {
    packsToReplenish: 0,
    samples: []
};
```

This would work;